# reading IP address of a host machine inside a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is there a way to know the IP address of a CentOS host machine inside the docker container inside which the container is running? Like say if I have a linux machine 10.10.10.10 IP that has docker container1 and container2 running, I would want to query the IP from my java code. The Java code is inside the docker container. I am actually running these services as a docker swarm.

Comment: I think some extra information about _why_ you're trying to do this might be important as there could be an alternative way (i.e. rather than IP, some magic). For example, typically the Docker host has the *internal* IP 172.17.0.1 - so that might do you for whatever you're up to. Of course, it's useless if you're publishing that IP outside of your containers...

Answer (score 1):

Docker is about isolating the container from the host.

So, in theory, the container should not be aware fo this IP address, unless the host "gives" it to the container

Some ideas

In an environment variable at run time

either

`docker run -e "host_IP=10.10.10.10"...`

or in a file my_env containing

`host_IP 10.10.10.10` and use it in

`docker run --env-file my_env`

see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

in an environment variable at build time

have in your Dockerfile a line

`ENV host_IP 10.10.10.10`

the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

you can share /etc/hosts between the host and the container with

`docker run -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts ...`

Comment: thanks, I felt the same.  However, giving an IP as an environ var inside Dockerfile will be a bad idea I guess if the IP of the host machine changes as I have to rebuild the docker image. Isn't it? I was also thinking of giving the environ var during runtime but if the IP of the host machine changes, I have to restart the container to get the new ip. Right?

Comment: Correct, so the option of `-v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts` or other ideas. See also http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/docker/6481/passing-secret-data-to-a-running-container#t=201705181637267206782

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following netstat command to find the host ip from inside a container:

```
netstat -nr | grep '^0.0.0.0' | awk '{print $2}'
```